# How to draw borders between cells in react-virtualized Table

Tags: react-virtualized

I am using `Table` component from `react-virtualized` to render a dataset of 1,000 rows and 20 columns. Even after reading documentation for [Table](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md) and [Column](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Column.md) and after a few experiments, I am not able to draw borders between cells in my Table.
Examples from [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/) with borders include only `Grid` component, such as [Grid](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Grid) and [CellMeasurer](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/CellMeasurer).

It think that `Grid` has a different implementation of cells than `Table` which appears to use flexboxes? Notice in the images below that a cell "content" in `Grid` occupies whole cell whereas in `Table` only a portion.

[image: cell in a Grid]
[image: cell in a Table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Table` component uses flexbox layout so you can still do what you're aiming for, using flex styles.

For example, you can specify a `rowStyle={{alignItems: "stretch"}}` so that the columns fill the full height of the row. Then if you want to vertically center column text, you can specify a `Column` prop `style={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center"}}`.

(The same can also be done with CSS classes of course.)

Answer (score 1):

This should more or less get you what you need, although this may not be the correct way to override. I just started working with react-virtualized yesterday so I'm still toying around with things.

```
@border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;

.column() {
    align-items: center;
    border-right: @border;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 0;

    &:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }
}

/*** Overrides for react-virtualized styles ***/
.ReactVirtualized__Table__Grid {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: @border;
    border-right: @border;
}
.ReactVirtualized__Table__headerColumn {
    .column();
}
.ReactVirtualized__Table__headerRow {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #efefef);
    border: @border;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.ReactVirtualized__Table__row {
    border-bottom: @border;
    border-left: @border;
}
.ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn {
    .column();
}
```